# Can your starting villagers move out in ACNH?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

One of my starting villagers is Stinky, and I want him to leave but I don’t know if your 2 starting villagers can actually move out. I haven’t talked to him in about 6 days.

I’ve gotten two other villagers (non-starters) to leave, so I know how to do it. Can someone pls help?

Answer (score 5):

All villagers can decide to leave - it is simply random chance which ones might consider it at any given time; there is nothing special about your first two villagers.